# Time showing differently for different users

Tags: excel, time

I own a file. I have set the time format to hh:mm:ss and input it, for example, as 00:00:10 (ten seconds).

However, some users see it displayed in the formula bar as 12:00:10 AM. This then messes up graphs and causes the file to be "corrected" by users further along.

I have read that the Formula Bar always formats any cell with a Time or Date format as time of day, but that is not the case and on my machine the formula bar displays it as hh:mm:ss.

The file is format protected.

So, how is it being displayed differently for some users?

Comment: Let me guess... these users are in different countries?

Comment: Nope, same company, same building, same version of Excel.

Comment: The format of the display in the formula bar is determined by the Windows Regional Settings (I think for the `Long Time` format for time entries). It seems your choices are to educate your users; hide the formula bar; change the users computer regional setting.

Comment: Oh, and if the display in the formula bar "messes up graphs" then there is something else wrong on that computer or with your workbook.  The information should be being stored in the same manner.

Comment: Thanks Ron - indeed the graph error was caused by the user "correcting" the time that was displayed in the formula bar. The underlying data, if untouched, was fine.
Can you give me an example of the Regional Setting cause/appearance?

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  On my system, if the long time format shows AM/PM, then that will show up that way in the formula bar; and if it doesn't, it won't.  So just change them on the "bad" computer. It is one of the options on the Control Panel, but I don't know the shortcut to get to that screen directly.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you may share the answer in the Answer tab, to remove this question from 'unanswered' list. & Marcoq can accept it like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). | Alternatively, the question owner (Marcoq) may do so too.. ( :

Answer (score 1):

The format of the display in the formula bar is determined by the Windows Regional Settings (I think for the Long Time format for time entries). It seems your choices are to educate your users; hide the formula bar; change the users computer regional setting.

Oh, and if the display in the formula bar "messes up graphs" then there is something else wrong on that computer or with your workbook. The information should be being stored in the same manner.